# Removing the sort arrow from DataGrid programmatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, listcollectionview

In my WPF application, I have a `DataGrid` with some columns that displays my sortable data. The user can sort and subsort whichever column he wants.

I added a button that should clear the sorting and return the `DataGrid` to its unsorted state using the MVVM pattern (meaning that the button is bound to a `RelayCommand` in the ViewModel, that clears the DataGrid's datasource's `SortDescriptions`.)

This is how the code looks now:

```
ViewModelLocator.MyViewModel.GroupedItems.SortDescriptions.Clear();
```

The DataGrid's `DataSource` is the `GroupedItems` object (of type `ListCollectionView`). When I click the button, I see that the DataGrid returns to its original, non-sorted state, however, the sorting arrows in the column headers remain as if the DataGrid is still sorted. How can I programmatically remove these arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove arrows in `DataGrid` try:

```
foreach (var column in dt.Columns)
{
    column.SortDirection = null;
}
```

Where `dt` is `DataGrid`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to remove them without having to know my `DataGrid` control?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not encountered anything like this. I doubt it is possible :(

Comment: You mean for all datagrid controls in your application ? If so, you can loop through the control types and if type is datagrid then you can set the above property to null !

Comment: I guess there isn't a way to do so programmatically, which is weird.
Thanks for the answers folks